# Express Static cannot find files starting with a hashtag

Tags: node.js, express, static

`static` doesn't find files starting with `#` 
I'm aware of the `dotfiles` option, however setting it to true doesn't solve the problem.

Is there `hashtagfiles` or similar option or another solution?

Here is the error message I get:

Request: `http://localhost:17863/z7gfYLhXn3zDg5QQ/admiralmarkets-live/#AAPL60.gz`

```
Error: Resource not found
at catchPageNotFound (D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\index.js:95:17)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
at next (D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
at Function.handle (D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (D:\BitBucket\EA Studio\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

My code is:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/data"), {setHeaders: setGzipHeaders, dotfiles: "allow"}));
```

If I rename the file to `_AAPL60.gz`, the request works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> static doesn't find files starting with #

A hashtag is used in a URL as a client-side fragment identifier and is not sent to the server by the broswer. So, the problem isn't that `express.static()` isn't finding it, but rather that that browser isn't sending the `#AAPL60.gz` to the server at all.

If you want it sent to the server, you need to encode it properly with `%23` like:

http://localhost:17863/z7gfYLhXn3zDg5QQ/admiralmarkets-live/%23AAPL60.gz

Though it is probably a lot simpler for all to use a character there that is allowed in URLs as a regular character such as `-` or `_` or some other allowed alpha-numeric character.

Comment: Excellent! I just replaced all "#" with "%23" and it works: `const encodedSymbol: string = symbol.replace(/#/g, "%23");`

Comment: @MiroslavPopov a better way I think is to use the build-in function `encodeURIComponent('#')` which produces `%23`